# Laravel 5 Querying with relations causes "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null" error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have been trying to create a simple user management system but keep on hitting road blocks when it comes to querying relations.  For example I have **users** and **roles** and whenever I try to make a query for all users and their roles I get an error.  The one in the title is only the latest one I've encountered.

My User and Role Models look like this:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'fk_role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

---

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('\App\Role', 'fk_user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```

My migration table for many-to-many relationship between the two looks like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); //fk => users
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); //fk => roles

            $table->foreign('fk_user_role')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('fk_role_user')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

And then I try to get all records with their relation in a controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('roles')->get();

    return $users;
}
```

So I need another pair of eyes to tell me what is it I am missing here?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You are missing **return** statements in the methods that define relations. They need to return relation definition.

Replace

```
public function roles()
{
    $this->belongsToMany('\App\Role', 'fk_user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

With

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

Comment: Also for anyone else reading this with the same problem I needed to fix the second parameter from "fk_user_role" to "role_user".

Comment: It's frustrating, it's just not returning

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a Laravel join related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149031/laravel-join-query-with-conditions ?

Answer (score 13):

You forgot the **return** in your functions

Do:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'fk_role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id');
```

```
return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Role', 'fk_user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use Return for your function's result. If you do not do that, Laravel does not know What should do with that function without any action.
Just use like this

```
return $this->hasOne(xxx, xx, xx);
```

Enjoy your coding !

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have written return in your model function relation.

```
return $this->hasMany('App\StaffShift','user_id','user_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Role Model:

```
 class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'fk_role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

User model

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Role', 'fk_user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
}
```