# Laravel join query with conditions

Tags: laravel, query-builder, join, laravel-query-builder

I have 4  tables.

**User** table:

```
id    col1     col2
```

**CoursesAssigned** table:

```
id    user_id      course_id       approved
```

**CourseInfo** table:

```
id     parent_id
```

**CourseParents** table:

```
id    start_date      end_date
```

**I think the table names and its column names are self explanatory.**

I have 2 kinds of users - i) assigned ii) unassigned. I show them in 2 different pages.

While showing the assigned students I need those students from **users** table for each of whom there is **at least** one row in **CoursesAssigned** table where `user_id` is his own user id and the `approved` field is 1 and the `course_id` in that row has  its own `parent_id` (from **CourseInfo**) with `end_date` (from **CourseParents**) greater than or equal to today.

For showing unassigned students, I need those students from **users** table, for each of whom -

either

there is **NO** row  in **CoursesAssigned** table where the `user_id` is his own user id and the `approved` column has a value 1. That is for an unassigned user, there may exist a row with his own user id but the `approved` field contains 0.

or

there may be rows in **CoursesAssigned** table with the `user_id` being his own user id and the `approved` field having a value 1 but the `parent_id` obtained from **CourseInfo** has from **CourseParents** an `end_date`  which is less than today's date.

I can write a query for assigned students  like:

```php
    $date=date('Y-m-d');

    $records = User::join('CoursesAssigned','users.id','=','CoursesAssigned.user_id')
                 ->join('CourseInfo','CourseInfo.id','=','CoursesAssigned.course_id')
                  ->join('CourseParents','CourseParents.id','=',
'CourseInfo.parent_id')
                  ->where('CoursesAssigned.approved','=',1)
                  ->where('CourseParents.end_date','>=',$date)
                  ->select('users.id','users.col1','users.col2')
                  ->orderBy('users.id','desc');
```

But that should not produce the correct result as that does not check   **CoursesAssigned** table for at **least** 1 row   that meets all mentioned criteria. Q1) **Or should it ?**

Q2) What is about the query that fetches only the unassigned students ?

**EDIT :** The answer can be in ORM, query builder or even raw MySql for Laravel format.

**EDIT2 :**    Let me clarify the scenario here :
I need to fetch both assigned and unassigned users separately.

To obtain assigned users  I have 1 rule: How can I get those users who have at least 1 approved course in **CoursesAssigned** table and the parent (obtained from **CourseInfo** table )of  that course has the end_date (in **CourseParents** table) greater than or equal to today.

To obtain unassigned students I have 2 rules :

**Rule 1:** Get those tudents who do not have any approved course (i.e. all courses have approved =0). They are unassigned students

**Rule 2:** Get those students who have approved courses but none of the approved courses meet the criteria of those for assigned students .  That means there is  no approved course there that has a parent  whose end_date is greater than or equal to today.They are also unassigned students.

Comment: You should look up laravel's documentation on eloquent and relationships. This can all be achieved in a precise manner with ease.

Comment: I detailed my effort

Comment: You should be using Eloquent relationships for performing the queries instead of using the query builder. Do you have relationships defined in the models? See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Comment: @pseudoanime, what relationship are you asking about ?  There are models and corresponding DB tables as well ?

Comment: is there a coursesassigned relationship in the users table (for example). It should be something along the lines of the following in the User model : public function coursesAssigned()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CoursesAssigned');
    } If you do, post all your relationships

Comment: @pseudoanime, suppose I have. Do you have any solution using ORM ?

Comment: @pseudoanime, I think the relationships you are talking about can be pretty easily assumed from the database table structure I mentioned

Comment: @pseudoanime, A user can have one or many courses in `CoursesAssigned` table. Each course in that table will have a parent in `CourseInfo` table.  Each parent (i.e.  row) in this table will have its details in `CourseParents`  table.

Comment: Can you ask a simplified question, maybe you can rephrase the question something like: `How can I get all assigned users where approved is 1`.

Comment: I tried to make the question precise. Let me clarify here : I need to fetch 2 kinds of users - 1) assigned 2) unassigned.. Unassigned users will be obtained applying 2 rules (written as either, or  in OP) while assigned users will be obtained using 1 rule.

Comment: @TheAlpha, gonna make an edit in OP.

Comment: @TheAlpha, added EDIT2

Comment: @TheAlpha, rephrased Edit2

Comment: What is the `course_id` in `CoursesAssigned `, is that a foreign key of `CourseInfo ` that maps to `id` in the `CourseInfo `?

Comment: @TheAlpha, your guess is right , `course_id` in `CoursesAssigned` is a foreign key of  `CourseInfo` that maps to `id` in the `CourseInfo`. I said in OP `I think the table names and its column names are self explanatory`. However, I clarified it now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not completely sure about your table relationships but from my guess, I came up with the following solution, first create the relationships using `Eloquent` models:

User Model (for `usres` table):

```
namespace App;

use App\Course;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class);
    }
}
```

Course Model (for `CoursesAssigned` table):

```
namespace App;

use App\CourseInfo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'CoursesAssigned';

    public function courseInfo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CourseInfo::class);
    }
}
```

CourseInfo Model (for `CourseInfo` table):

```
namespace App;

use App\CourseParent;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CourseInfo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'CourseInfo';

    public function courseParent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CourseParent::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

CourseParent Model (for `CourseParents` table):

```
namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CourseParent extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'CourseParents';

}
```

Get the assigned users:

```
$assignedUsers = User::whereHas('courses', function($query) {
    $query->where('approved', 1)
          ->with(['courses.courseInfo.courseParent' => function($query) {
              $query->where('end_date', >= \Carbon\Carbon::now());
          }]);
})->get(); // paginate(...) for paginated result.
```

This should work if my assumption is correct. Try this for `assignedUsers` first then let me know and then I'll look into it for the other requirements. Also make sure that you do understand about Eloquent relationships between models and implement everything correctly (with correct namespace).

---

Note: This answer is incomplete and need further info because the answer is a result of direct conversation with `OP` over phone (OP called me because I was reachable) so some changes will be made overtime if needed and will be continued step by step until I can come up with a solution or leave it.

Comment: The last `where` part is `$query->where('end_date', >= \Carbon\Carbon::now())`. I changed this part to `$query->where('end_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d') )`. ANd with a `dd()` function I found the query to be `select * from users where exists (select * from coursesassigned where coursesassigned.user_id = users.id and approved = 1)`.  That means the `courseInfo.courseParent` relation is ingored. What should be done here ?

Comment: Maybe you didn't follow the instructions properly. Make sure all relationships are created inside each models. What you `dd`, Have you get the full query, change the `get->` to `->toSql()` and then `dd($assignedUsers)`.

Comment: I removed the `->get()` part, then used `echo " sql = ".$assignedUsers->toSql();` and `dd($assignedUsers->toSql(), $assignedUsers->getBindings());`. But did not get the expected result

Comment: I checked the relations as well and those are correct. The solution can be in ORM, query builder or raw Mysql for Laravel format as well

Comment: What is about query builder or raw MySQL ?

Comment: Check the update and try now. check `with(['courses.courseInfo.courseParent' => function($query) {...})`.

Comment: The with part was `->with(['courseInfo.courseParent' => function($query) {...})` but it should have `->with(['courses.courseInfo.courseParent' => function($query) {...})`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179643/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-the-alpha).